# What is the difference between 'sudo apt autoremove' and 'sudo apt-get autoremove'?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I thought `apt` is just a new software which works exactly like `apt-get`. I always used them interchangeably. But it seems they are different, at least in the `autoremove` function.
I ran `sudo apt autoremove` which didn't remove anything but then I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove` and it removed a lot of packages. Is there something inherently different between the two?

Comment: @pa4080 The answers there basically just says that apt is apt-get plus some default flags for different commands. But even in the list provided in one answer, 'autoremove' is not present. So, that question doesn't have the answer to the difference in the behavior for autoremove. Although I should have searched for that before asking this, still, I don't think that answers my question.

Comment: @lucifer I haven't seen any such difference in behaviour. Please provide the actual commands you ran and the output you got, and if possible, a reproducible example.

Comment: @muru I just ran `sudo apt autoremove` and then `sudo apt-get autoremove`. I cannot reproduce it. It occurred while I was trying to update 16.04 LTS to 18.04.01 LTS. I will try to reproduce it and post again.
Still, being so lightning fast at closing questions, hats off to you guys!